# Change color of button in Kendo upload widget

Tags: colors, upload, kendo-ui

How to change the color of "Select" button in Kendo Upload widget.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload().Name("files").Async(a => a
            .Save(WorkflowControllers.CommissionsAdjustments.ActionNames.Upload, WorkflowControllers.CommissionsAdjustments.Name)
            .Remove(WorkflowControllers.CommissionsAdjustments.ActionNames.Remove, WorkflowControllers.CommissionsAdjustments.Name)
            .AutoUpload(true))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "#=AgentID#"})
            .Events(events => events.Upload("onUploadDocuments").Remove("onRemoveDocuments")).ToClientTemplate())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either have a global style:

```
.k-upload-button {
    background-color: white;
}
```

or set it for a specific button if you have a context element to search in:

```
$("#buttonContext").find(".k-upload-button").css({ "background-color": "razmatazz" });
```